# End-To-End encryption for VoIP teleconference applications and many-to-many lag-sensitive applications

Tags: encryption, data-privacy, voip

There are various protocols that allow you to have privacy-enhanced chat.

Those can be either 2-party chat such as:

- OTR
- SIGNAL

or multiparty chat such as:

- SIGNAL
- (n+1)sec
- mpOTR
- GOTR (2013 spec and 2008 ones)

But nowadays many protocols, alongside with Instant Messaging (IM), support multi-party video and voice exchange such as Skype and Google Hangouts. What protocols exist to ensure the security properties on applications for privacy-enhanced multi-party/teleconference application?

I am asking because teleconference applications are lag-sensitive ones and there is the real-time factor as well. Also, the data flow is stream based ones instead of message-based ones so ratcheting per message - like signal does - is a no-go (because there is no message concept, to begin with).

The common key for the VoIP group can be done via exchanging special messages and running a Group Key Authentication protocol but what about forward secrecy and the transcript integrity protection messages?

Do you know any protocols that support multi-party VoIP as well (even academic purpose-oriented ones without any practical value)?

Comment: Please at least download an English dictionary and spell check before submission. Why do you think ratcheting (or "racheting") is not possible? Ratchets are generally not very CPU intensive and you can certainly split streams into separate packets / messages.